# How to create a new account without resign in Firebase? in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Good afternoon! The user is logged in the system (there are two options through email or Google Plus), then he has a department in the application where it can create departments of its stores, and create it the user can using the email of the department and set a password for the subsequent pass to a particular department. To create a new user, we use this `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser` but if you use this code, it makes Firebase relogin, and already comes with a new account. The question is how to create a new user, without resign with a new account?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want one user to be able to create multiple accounts for different departments in your app. Is that correct?

Comment: @JordiBruin Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this in multiple ways:

Option 1 : save the credentials of the admin user securely on your device. Then, when the user creates a new user, log in with the admin credentials. This will log you out and immediately log you back in.

Option 2 : use the admin sdk to create a user with a rest API call on the web side.

Comment: I thought about the first version, but I thought it was a bad decision, so I decided to ask whether there is the best.

Comment: Yeah I would suggest the second one as well!